# Uploading an image from an iphone app to a rails app with carrierwave

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm trying to send an image from an iPhone app to a rails app through an internal api using carrier wave. I've put most of the code together from other questions on stack overflow and examples online - i've never done this type of thing before. I don't have the iPhone code as we're outsourcing it, but I can get it.

The code in my ApiController that receives the request looks like this:

```
  def create_item
    @item = upload_image(params[:img], params[:name], params[:content_type], params[:file_size])
  end

  private

  def upload_image(img, name, content_type, file_size)
    encoded_img = Base64.encode64(img)
    io = FilelessIO.new(Base64.decode64(encoded_img))
    io.original_filename = "#{name}"
    item = Item.new

    item.cover = io
    item.content_type = content_type
    item.file_size = file_size
    item.save!(validate: false)
    item
  end
```

When they send the request the parameters look like the code below and it gives them a 500 error.

```
Parameters: {"img"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc3b1f4f570 @original_filename="avatar.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"img\"; filename=\"avatar.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130703-2-hfx7gg>>;, "controller"=>"api/v1/api", "action"=>"create_item", "uid"=>"100003052137695"}
```

The error I get is:

```
  no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String
  vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/base64.rb:38:in `pack'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get indicates that iPhone is sending the actual file whereas you expect it to send a Base64 string from your code.

Check with your iPhone team and agree upon needed format:

1. They send Base64 string and you should get past this error
2. You change your code to accept the file (something like `item.cover = params[:img]`)

HTH